# /etc/ld.so.conf doesn't contain /usr/lib

Tags: path, libraries, pkg-config

I am using `pkg-config` to help supply the correct libs during c++ compilation. As I understand it, it searches in directories supplied by `/etc/ld.so.conf`. My `ld.so.conf` references the following lib locations via an include directive pointing to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`:

```
/usr/local/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Problem is the library I need is under `/usr/lib` by default.

Can I just add in this path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` myself or move the library or what is the recommended practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pkg-config doesn't use ld.so.conf at all, it normally stores config files in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`, (specify PKG_CONFIG variable if needed)

i.e `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libmtp.pc`

```
# libmtp pkg-config source file

prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libmtp
Description: libmtp is a library for accessing Media Transfer Protocol devices
Version: 1.1.5
Requires: libusb-1.0
Conflicts:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lmtp
Libs.private: -lgcrypt 
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

You can find cflags, libs etc. there, that's how pkg-config supply needed command parameters.

So, for your own lib, create a similar file ([read the doc here](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html))

Answer (score 7):

For clarification regarding `/etc/ld.so.conf`: this file is used by the dynamic (run-time) linker/loader (`ld-linux.so` on Linux), which resolves symbols in a binary that is loaded to be run (this includes shared libraries as well). This is in contrast with the linker `ld`, which is used to assemble several object/archive files together and resolves their dependencies.

The dynamic linker checks `/etc/ld.so.conf` for a list directories in which it should look for shared libraries when loading a binary. Apart from the paths mentioned there, the linker also searches its default paths (`/lib` and `/usr/lib` on Linux, usually changed to `lib64` for 64-bit loader) **unless** the binary was linked with a flag that explicitly disables this (`-x nodefaultlib` in binutils' `ld`), in which case it only honours `ld.so.conf`.